# Center a element on the svg

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, svg

I got this svg in D3.js with the size of (1000,1000) and a circle on that svg at  a certain random position for example (100,200).

Now, i want to shift my svg in a way, that the circle is at the middle/center of my svg, that means at (500,500). But I want to solve it with a function, that allows me to do this for a every random positioned circle.

Is there someone who can help? The svg upper left point of the SVG is currently at (0,0). So when move for example with `.attr("transform", "translate(10,10)");`, then the upper left point of the SVG with be at (10,10). Also i thought about using the centroid function like in this example:
https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2206529

But i don't know if that only works for world maps.

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg:svg") 
    .attr("width", 1000)
    .attr("height", 1000);

function move(){
    svg.transition()
        .duration(750)
        .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)");
}
```

Comment: can you share your mark up and svg code as well

Comment: Why don't you move the circle instead?

Comment: Because of the case, that there are many circles on scrren, i think it is beter to move the svg ;)

Comment: It still doesn't make sense: if you want to move the SVG because there are several circles, **which one** will be in the centre? And how is that different from moving the circle?

Comment: If you have many circles and move the circles, then they can overlap and i want to avoid this case. I want for example click on a circle and the svg moves there, like in this example of Mike Bostock: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2206529

Comment: In that example the SVG is not moving. Besides that, you can simply move all the circles. Or even better, put them in a group and move the group.

Comment: Oh, wait a minute. So i misunderstood that example of Mike Bostock. Thanks for the hint. Ok, so move all circles is a option. But how can i place a clicked circle in the middle of the screen/svg? Is there the centroid function needed?

Comment: @Suppe Check the edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this is probably not what you want, but it is in my opinion the simplest and cleanest approach: move the circle instead. Or, if you have several circles, move their container, that is, the `<g>` element.

The math for translating the group is simple:

```
.attr("transform", "translate(" + (w/2 - pX) + "," + (h/2 - pY) + ")")
```

Where `w` is the width of the SVG, `h` is the height, `pX` is the `x` coordinate of the circle and `pY` is the `y` coordinate of the circle.

Here is a simple demo. I'm generating 20 circles and, every 2 seconds, I'm choosing one of the circles (in sequence), which is highlighted in red, and translating the whole group to make that circle centred:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var g = svg.append("g")
var circles = g.selectAll(null)
  .data(d3.range(20).map(function() {
    return {
      x: Math.random() * 500,
      y: Math.random() * 300
    }
  }))
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return d.x
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return d.y
  })
  .attr("r", 10)
  .style("fill", "lime");

var counter = 0;

var timer = d3.interval(function() {
  if (counter === 19) {
    timer.stop()
  }
  var thisCircle = circles.filter(function(d, i) {
    return i === counter;
  });
  var position = thisCircle.datum();
  g.transition()
    .duration(1500)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + (250 - position.x) + "," + (150 - position.y) + ")");
  thisCircle.style("stroke", "red").style("stroke-width", 4)
    .transition()
    .delay(2000)
    .duration(0)
    .style("stroke", "none")
  counter++;
}, 2000)
```

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500" height="300"></svg>
```

EDIT:

For a click, use the same logic. Here is the demo:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var g = svg.append("g")
var circles = g.selectAll(null)
  .data(d3.range(20).map(function() {
    return {
      x: Math.random() * 500,
      y: Math.random() * 300
    }
  }))
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return d.x
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return d.y
  })
  .attr("r", 10)
  .style("fill", "lime")
  .style("cursor", "pointer");

circles.on("click", function(d) {
  g.transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + (250 - d.x) + "," + (150 - d.y) + ")")
})
```

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500" height="300"></svg>
```

Comment: Very nice, thanks! Can you please explain this line? `var thisCircle = circles.filter(function(d, i) {
    return i === counter;
  });`

Comment: I used that to select one circle at the time, in ascending order.

Comment: And `var position = thisCircle.datum();` gives you the (x,y) coordinates of the circle? Isn't `data()` there to bind data to DOM elements?

Comment: It's just 1 element, hence `datum`.